# JSF xhtml contar cada que se entra en el catch del bean

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml

Estoy usando jsf(xhtml) y tengo  donde
quiero que vaya sumando cada vez que en el bean entra en el catch, sin embargo en inputText siempre queda en 0 y no realiza la suma de
acuerdo al código.

Pero no me funciona, he intentado lo siguiente.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
              xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
              xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h:form id="vacanteForm">
                    <h:messages globalOnly="true" ></h:messages>
                   <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td><h:outputLabel for="miContador" value="mi contador" ></h:outputLabel></td>
                            <td><h:inputText id="miContador" value="#{ejemplo.miContador}"></h:inputText></td> <!-- quiero que aqui sume cada que entra en el catch-->
                            <td><h:message for="ciudad"></h:message></td>
                        </tr>                         
                    </table>
                            
                    <h:commandButton id="enviar" action="#{ejemplo.enviar}" value="enviar" >
                    </h:commandButton>
                </h:form>
            </body>
        </html>
```

y en mi clase bean:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class ejemplo extends Object {

    private int miContador;

    Logger log = LogManager.getRootLogger();

    public ejemplo() {
       
    }

    public String enviar() {
  
                String mensaje = "exitoso.";
                FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, mensaje, mensaje);
                FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                String componentId = null;//este es un mensaje global
                facesContext.addMessage(componentId, facesMessage);
                
                try {
                    int i = 100/0;
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        this.miContador = this.miContador+1; // quiero regresar esta varible a mi jsf(xhtml) y que se valla sumando cada que entre aqui 
                    } 
                
                return "index";           
    }
       
    public int getmiContador() {
        return miContador;
    }

    public void setmiContador(int miContador) {
        this.miContador = miContador;
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano por cualquier ayuda, estoy pendiente por cualquier duda.

Comment: Hola! Te recomiendo completar el [tour] de SOes para conocer mejor el sitio y ganar tu primera medalla. Por otra parte, te recomendaría que intentaras seguir las convenciones de estilo de Java en tu código: nombres de clases comenzando con mayúscula, camelCase para todos los nombres (getMiContador, por ejemplo).

Comment: De acuerdo gracias.

Comment: Creo que no está funcionando justo por lo que te marca @PabloLozano. Cuando usas `ejemplo.miContador` en jsf internamente se debe traducir a `ejemplo.getMiContador()`

Comment: En mi modesta opinión, el problema es que cuando se carga la página, el inputText toma el valor de miContador... jamás se vuelve a actualizar.